# SQL Server Query Count Join Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables are call `Suppliers` and `Products`, which products have `SupplierID` as foreign key.

My question is how to make a query that can show this result

```
Supplier Name | Total Products
--------------+---------------
Unilever      | 20
Kalbe         | 50
Jhonson       | 70
```

My table structure

- `Suppliers` => ID, Name
- `Products` => ID, SupplierID, Brand, Price

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM Products
GROUP BY SupplierID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
    s.Name as 'Supplier Name', count(p.ID) as 'Total Products'
from 
    Supliers as s
left outer join 
    Producsts as p on (s.Id = p.SupplierID)
group by 
    s.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need in addition to your query is a sub-query to obtain the name:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Total
  , (select Name from Supplier where ID = SupplierID) as [Supplier Name]
FROM Products
GROUP BY SupplierID
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `left join by SuplierID + subquery for Products group by SuplierID` to avoid multi slow query.

```sql
select T1.Name as Supplier Name
 ,T2.cnt as Total Product
from Supliers T1
left join (
    select SuplierID,count(1) cnt
    from Products
    group by SuplierID
) T2 on T1.ID = T2.SuplierID
```